# Kotlin - Pass array of functions as argument to function

Tags: kotlin

I have this function that (theoretically) accept an array of functions as argument.

```
fun execute(afterDay: Long, listeners: Array<(List<String>) -> Unit>)
```

In the client class I trying to call this execute method and pass functions as parameter:

```
fun updateMovies(ids: Array<String>){

}

fun getNewIds() {
    GetImdbIds(kodein).execute(daysBack.toEpochDay(), [::updateMovies])
}
```

But it doesn't compiles.

What I'm doing wrong?

the error:

```
Error:(29, 59) Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Array<KFunction1<@ParameterName Array<String>, Unit>> but Array<(List<String>) -> Unit> was expected
Error:(29, 59) Kotlin: Unsupported [Collection literals outside of annotations]
```

Comment: he said 'unresolved reference' but I realized the function should be declared before. Now the error is:  Error:(29, 59) Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Array<KFunction1<@ParameterName Array<String>, Unit>> but Array<(List<String>) -> Unit> was expected
Error:(29, 59) Kotlin: Unsupported [Collection literals outside of annotations]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this to work by making two changes.

First, your `updateMovies` function as written takes an `Array<String>`, when your `listeners` wants functions that take `List<String>`. So, we can make this change:

```
fun updateMovies(ids: List<String>) {
    TODO()
}
```

Next, if you create your array of function references using `arrayOf()` instead of attempting an illegal array literal, this should compile:

```
GetImdbIds(kodein).execute(1L, arrayOf(::updateMovies))
```